# Sending headers/body after the websocket session is established

Tags: session, websocket, spring-websocket

I am using org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.client.WebSocketClient to establish a websocket connection.
After the initial handshake(Protocol switch/Upgrade) the websocket session is established.

Here is the code snipped i am using:

```
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
client.start();
URI echoUri = new URI("destinationURI");
ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();      
request.setHeader("myCustomHeader", "CustomHeader");    
client.connect(socket, echoUri, request);

Collection<WebSocketSession> sessions = client.getConnectionManager().getSessions();
for (WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) {
    webSocketSession.getRemote().sendString("<Custome message>");//I am able to recieve the messages //to the configured message handler
}
```

My message handler looks like:

```
@Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session,
            TextMessage message//This is what i sent above) throws Exception {
        session.getHandshakeHeaders();//This has "myCustomHeader", "CustomHeader"
        BinaryMessage binaryMessage = new BinaryMessage(new String(
                "Hello . This is message sent from server").getBytes());
        session.sendMessage(binaryMessage);
    }
```

Is it possible to send a custom header, after the web socket session is established?

Here is what i tried:

```
WebSocketClient client = new WebSocketClient();
client.start();
URI echoUri = new URI("destinationURI");
ClientUpgradeRequest request = new ClientUpgradeRequest();      
request.setHeader("myCustomHeader", "CustomHeader");    
client.connect(socket, echoUri, request);
Collection<WebSocketSession> sessions = client.getConnectionManager().getSessions();
for (WebSocketSession webSocketSession : sessions) {
    webSocketSession.getUpgradeRequest().setHeader("mySecondCustomHeader","MySecondCustomHeader");
    webSocketSession.getRemote().sendString("<Custome message>");//I am able to recieve the messages //to the configured message handler
}
```

I am only getting myCustomHeader and not mySecondCustomHeader in session.getHandshakeHeaders()

```
@Override
    protected void handleTextMessage(WebSocketSession session,
            TextMessage message//This is what i sent above) throws Exception {
        session.getHandshakeHeaders();//This has "myCustomHeader", "CustomHeader"
        BinaryMessage binaryMessage = new BinaryMessage(new String(
                "Hello . This is message sent from server").getBytes());
        session.sendMessage(binaryMessage);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

> s it possible to send a custom header, after the web socket session is
>   established?

No, it is not possible. Once the HTTP negotiation has concluded, the connection only uses binary frames to communicate and cannot do more HTTP interactions.

Comment: I am basically looking at the API's functionality as well. What is the function/purpose of  webSocketSession.getUpgradeRequest().setHeader();? The documentation isn't sufficient.

Comment: Probably there is another method you can override where you can hook code to the HTTP negotiation, and there you can add stuff to the HTTP response.

Comment: Small addition: the WebSocket spec allows for speaking HTTP again after a WebSocket closing handshake has been performed - on the same, non-closed underlying TCP connection.

Comment: Definitely. That is the usual HTTP 1.0 "persistent connection" concept.